# Scrape data as <li> between two known keyword encapsulated as <b> tag

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to **scrape** [this kind of product](https://www.zooplus.fr/shop/chats/aliments_specifiques_therapeutiques_chat/royal_canin_veterinary_diet/reins_voies_urinaires_chat_croquettes_royal_canin/301504). I want to **scrape** data as `<li>` between `<b>`Indication`</b>`and `<b>`Contre-indications`</b>` and then the next `<b></b>` for each there is not predictable keyword.

Here is the source code of the requested page.

```
<article class="col-md-10 col-md-push-1">

<p><b>Caractéristiques des croquettes pour chat Royal Canin Veterinary Diet - Urinary S/O LP 34 :</b>
</p><ul>
<li>struvite.</li>

<li>la vessie.</li>

<li>d'oxalate de calcium.
</li>

<li>maintien de la muqueuse vésicale </li></ul><p></p>

<p><b>Remarques :</b>
</p><ul>
<li> Urinary S/O Feline</li>
<li>chez le chat âgé, rénal avant la prescription de l'Urinary  S/O Feline</li></ul><p></p>

<p><b>Indications :</b>
</p><ul>

<li>dissolution des calculs urinaires de struvite</li>
<li>gestion des récidives d’urolithiase à struvite et à oxalate de calcium dans un seul aliment</li></ul><p></p>

<p><b>Contre-indications :</b>
</p><ul>
<li>insuffisance rénale chronique, acidose métabolique</li> 
<li>traitement avec des médicaments acidifiant l'urine</li>
<li>lactation, gestation, croissance</li></ul><p></p>

<p><b>Durée du traitement :</b> 5 à 12 semaines sont nécessaires pour obtenir la dissolution des calculs de struvites.<br>
P</p>
                    </article>
```

**First approach** : with regex, parse as free text. Didn't manage to obtain anything great with this regular formula `(<b>[Ii]ndication[s]{0,1}.*?</b>)([\n\r]*.*)(<b>Contre-[Ii]ndication[s]{0,1}.*?</b>)`. It was working [okay in the tester](https://regex101.com/r/XVp4BO/1) but the .re in Python wasn't finding any match. Okay let's move on.

**Second Approach** : I tried to extract using scrapy :

```
l.add_xpath('contre_indication','//*[@id="description-panel"]/div/article/b[starts-with(text(),"Contre-indications")]/following-sibling::ul/li/text()')
l.add_xpath('contre_indication','//*[@id="description-panel"]/div/article/p/b[starts-with(text(),"Contre-indications")]/following-sibling::ul/li/text()')
l.add_xpath('indication','//*[@id="description-panel"]/div/article/b[starts-with(text(),"Indication")]/following-sibling::ul/li/text()')
l.add_xpath('indication','//*[@id="description-panel"]/div/article/p/b[starts-with(text(),"Indication")]/following-sibling::ul/li/text()')
```

Sometimes the keyword xpath is a /b/ alone and sometimes a /p/b. This is the reason why there is two xpath for each.
Here at best I have the whole text between `<li>` but with not distinction of Indication/Contre-indications.

Expected output would be :

```
Indication : ["dissolution des calculs urinaires de struvite","gestion des récidives d’urolithiase à struvite et à oxalate de calcium dans un seul aliment"]
Contre-indication : ["insuffisance rénale chronique, acidose métabolique"..."lactation, gestation, croissance"]
```

I'm very keen to know the working approach of this kind of problem.

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can acomplish this with `xpath` selectors:

```
'//p[contains(b/text(),"Contre-indications")]/following-sibling::ul[1]/li/text()'
```

Explaining the xpath:

`//p` - select all paragraph nodes
`[contains(b/text(),"Contre-indications")]` - that contain some text in child node b's text
`//following-sibling::ul[1]` - select sibling of paragraph node that is first of unordered list kind.
`//li/text()` - select text of any children that are list nodes

If you run it in scrapy shell:

```
$ scrapy shell
> body = ...
> from parsel import Selector
> sel = Selector(text=body)
> sel.xpath('//p[contains(b/text(),"Indication")]/following-sibling::ul[1]/li/text()').extract()
['dissolution des calculs urinaires de struvite', 'gestion des récidives d’urolithiase à struvite et à oxalate de calcium dans un seul aliment']
> sel.xpath('//p[contains(b/text(),"Contre-indications")]/following-sibling::ul[1]/li/text()').extract()
['insuffisance rénale chronique, acidose métabolique', "traitement avec des médicaments acidifiant l'urine", 'lactation, gestation, croissance']
```